# How do I change a torch tensor to concat with another tensor

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to concatenate a tensor of numerical data with the output tensor of a resnet-50 model.  The output of that model is tensor shape `torch.Size([10,1000])` and the numerical data is tensor shape `torch.Size([10, 110528,8])` where the `10` is the batch size, `110528` is the number of observations in a data frame sense, and 8 is the number of columns (in a dataframe sense).  I need to reshape the numerical tensor to `torch.Size([10,8])` so it will concatenate properly.

How would I reshape the tensor?

Comment: Probably ask this on SE Cross Validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting tensors.

```
a = torch.randn(10, 1000)
b = torch.randn(10, 110528, 8)
```

New tensor to allow concatenate.

```
c = torch.zeros(10,1000,7)
```

Check shapes.

```
a[:,:,None].shape, c.shape
```

```
(torch.Size([10, 1000, 1]), torch.Size([10, 1000, 7]))
```

Alter tensor `a` to allow concatenate.

```
a = torch.cat([a[:,:,None],c], dim=2)
```

Concatenate in dimension 1.

```
torch.cat([a,b], dim=1).shape
```

```
torch.Size([10, 111528, 8])
```